# In Google Analytics, is there a way to view the distribution of the data underlying the "average" stats?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

There are certain stats in Google Analytics, such as "Avg. Session Duration," which present arithmetical means. Arithmetical means are pretty useless if you don't know the distribution of your data (i.e. whether it's Gaussian).

For "Avg. Session Duration," specifically, you can view user-level data, export up to 5000 rows, and plot a histogram. However, I'd like to know if there is a *straightforward* way to view the distribution of *each* available "average ..." stats in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dreadnaught

Distribution for "Avg. Session Duration" you can see in "Audience - Behaviour - Engagement" report:

[image: Average session duration distribution]

Comment: Thanks. 1. Is there a way to change the binning (i.e. such that bins are of equal size)? 2. Do you know if it's possible to view the distribution for the "Avg. Time on Page" (from Behavior -> Overview) stat?

Comment: You can do it using "Site Speed User Timings" report but it will require some additional setup.

P.S. I also updated my answer above, as I noticed that I actually made screenshot from Google Analytics for mobile apps, rather than web-sites. Now report name and screenshot are shown for GA for web-sites.