# Is there a way to view the distribution for "Avg. Time on Page" in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

In Google Analytics, under "Behavior," there is an *Avg. Time on Page* stat, which indicates the mean time that users spent on the website in question. The mean is pretty meaningless without knowing the distribution of the data, so I'd like to know whether there is a way to view the distribution for *Avg. Time on Page*.

I had [previously asked this question about the "average" stats in the general sense](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104537/in-google-analytics-is-there-a-way-to-view-the-distribution-of-the-data-underly), and the question was answered for the *Avg. Session Duration* stat (with an allusion about how to do it for *Avg. Time on Page*), but now, I'd like to know specifically how to view the distribution, or to get the underlying data, from which the distribution can be calculated, for *Avg. Time on Page*. Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like it would be a useful report, but I've never found anything like it in GA.